# Drupal change the number of items in view PHP

Tags: views

I have a view page that show 10 elements. The idea is to make three buttons for the user to select if he wants to display 10 elements, 20 elements or 30 elements in the view page. Is there any way to do in PHP? I have search in Google but I can't find anything.

I know I can change in the View config -> Pager:

[image]

Comment: Expose it as an option in the view?

Comment: Yes, inside the views page

Comment: You’d need to write a custom pager plugin for that. It’s not too hard, the existing pager plugins would be a good place to start from

Answer (score 1):

insert HTML markup on the View header and make three buttons with HTML markup and then link each of the button like

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/search?items_per_page=10">10 elements</a></li>
  <li><a href="/search?items_per_page=20">20 elements</a></li>
  <li><a href="/search?items_per_page=30">30 elements</a></li>
</ul>
```

After this you can style the button however you want.